# Calculating total width of div with hidden images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to calculate the width of a div with 10 images of width 200px.

However the images have `overflow: hidden` in the css. I believe this means I can not get the correct value for the width. Do you know how I can somehow get the correct value of 2000 px and not the viewport width?

Here is a codepen example:

http://codepen.io/dwigt/pen/EWvoEo/?editors=1111

Comment: Thanks. I know of a solution since the images all have the same size. I just wish I can find a more "modular" approach that allows me to reuse the function.

Comment: if your css is fixed (typo) , it works fine as far as i can see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PpKRXd?editors=1111 white-space & padding is also included in calculation : 2096px returned

Comment: ... if you set font-size to 0, then 2060px is returned while white-space disappear sized down to 0 http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gmxzaQ?editors=1111

Comment: Thanks for the comments, it seems to be working. While using Chrome I was sometimes getting wrong answers even when it was working. No idea why. Nice tip regarding the white-space!

Comment: for a funny reason the tipo in the css confused the script while the answer of Masiama , below, did not care about it ;)

Answer (score 3):

`$('.scrollmenu')[0].scrollWidth`

Comment: still  `padding: 3x` css should be fixed to `padding: 3px;` ;)

Comment: You can calculate width of block by calculating width of all its children
`var width = 0;
Array.from($('.scrollmenu').children()).map(child => {
     width += child.scrollWidth;
})`